# How to translate ffmpeg linux comand into python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

I'm using this to join screenshots into a movie

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -framerate 1 -pattern_type glob -i "$1" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p $2
```

But is there a way to translate this command into ffmbeg-python python command?

If you could do it for me, please help!

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/blob/master/examples/README.md) is quite helpful and includes the following example:

**Assemble video from sequence of frames**

```
glob

(
    ffmpeg
    .input('/path/to/jpegs/*.jpg', pattern_type='glob', framerate=25)
    .output('movie.mp4')
    .run()
)
```

So try something like this:

```
glob

(
    ffmpeg
    .input('/path/to/jpegs/*.jpg', pattern_type='glob', framerate=1)
    .output('movie.mp4',pix_fmt='yuv420p')
    .run()
)
```

Comment: Thank you! But what does 'glob' do? And, so I basically import the module and paste that thing in?

Comment: As I said. The documentation is quite helpful. Read this https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python

Comment: And here's the API Reference: https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/